# Paginating a paginated API response

Tags: javascript, pagination

I have an application which requests data from a REST endpoint 50 items at a time and displays results in the UI. I would like to paginate each API response into *smaller* arrays for display and then request a *new* API resource when the user reaches the end of the children arrays.

[I have a working CodePen demo](https://codepen.io/bbennett/pen/NWWaPaX?editors=0010) using the SWAPI and paginating results (5 at a time) and I'm wondering if there is a better/more efficient way to achieve the same result.

```js
// See the CodePen for a working demo using these HTMl elements
const container = document.querySelector('#container');
const start = document.querySelector('#button');

let planetArrays = [];
let nextPage;
let refresh = true;

async function request(url) {

  // Call specific page of results if provided
  url = url || 'https://swapi.co/api/planets';

  var data = await fetch(url);
  var json = await data.json();

  return json;

}

async function getData() {

  let data = await request(nextPage)

  // Store the next page for future calls
  nextPage = data.next;

  // Split the big array into smaller arrays
  for(var d of data.results) {
    planetArrays.push(data.results.splice(0, 5));
  }

  // Return the spliced Array
  return planetArrays;

}

async function next() {  
  var childPage, response;

  // Define which child array in smallArrays to display
  var inSmallArray = isNaN(parseInt(start.dataset.page));

  childPage = (!inSmallArray) ? parseInt(start.dataset.page) : 0;

  // hit the API if it's a refresh call
  if(refresh) {
    var response = await getData(nextPage);
    refresh = false;
  } else {
    // if it's NOT the first call, get the stored array
    response = planetArrays;
  }

  // Do a check to see if we're on the last page in memory
  if(childPage >= planetArrays.length-1) {
    // Make a refresh call on the next click
    refresh = true;
  }

  container.innerText = "";

  for(var c = 0; c < response[childPage].length; c++) {
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.innerText = response[childPage][c].name;
    container.appendChild(p);
  }

  // iterate the planetArrays
  var newPage = childPage + 1;
  start.dataset.page = newPage;

}

start.addEventListener("click", next)
```